# Error al guardar datos con openpyxl , python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Estoy obteniendo una error al guardar información en una hoja de excel, realizo el ejercicio de cargar el libro y especifico la hoja en que guardaré la información y por ultimo uso el metodo .save, este efectivamente me guarda la información que quiero pero me deja el archivo sin formatos, tal como lo muestro en las imagenes

Estoy usando la versión: openpyxl   3.0.10

```
def AsignacionUEM():          
    print("Cargando libro")    
    lPCartera = openpyxl.load_workbook("D:/PLANTILLA/PLANTILLA.xlsm",read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
    print("Cargando hoja")
    hPCartera = lPCartera.worksheets[10]
    print("Agregando registros")
    for row in expAsig:
        hPCartera.append(row)

    print("Guardando excel . . .")
    lPCartera.save("D:/PLANTILLA/PLANTILLA_Envio.xlsm")
    lPCartera.close()
```

*** Archivo de excel con los formatos antes de manipularlo con openpyxl ***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo de excel como resultado de haberlo manipulado con openpxyl, este si guarda la información, pero me la deja sin formatos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hasta dónde sé, openpyxl no tiene soporte para los estilos, al menos,  leídos desde un archivo. Directamente los ignora. Creo que si se puede aplicar estilos por código pero una vez que ya has abierto la planilla.

Comment: Hola, Patricio muchas gracias por tu comentario, pero he trabajado varios proyectos en ese mismo equipo, solo que ahora me da ese error sin importar el proyecto o archivo que maneje , anteriormente no sucedía